# Scala function-value partial evaluation ambiguity (inlining?)

Tags: scala, optimization, functional-programming, expression, bytecode

In the following Scala snippet, I try to ensure that as much of the expression is "precompiled" so that the final full-application of the function literal incurs as few cpu-cycles as possible. i.e., I want to ensure that the if-condition is evaluated at the time of the function-literal assignment rather than later at the time of applying the function-literal to the unbound parameter.

```
private val tokenFilterFactory: TokenStream => TokenStream = 
  if(augment) {
    new AugmentingStemmingTokenFilter(_, markStems, bitPos, stemmerFactory())
  }
  else {
    new ReplacingStemmingTokenFilter(_, markStems, bitPos, stemmerFactory())
  }
```

What I want is to then apply the functional literal a large number of times, like 
    tokenFilterFactory(tokenStream)

My question: will the conditional `if(augment)` be executed every time the function literal is applied (bad), or will it be executed only once, when the function literal is defined/assigned? Context: scala 2.11

equivalently, is the above val-assignment run-time equivalent (only w.r.t. evaluation, not 'assignability') to the following snippet:

```
private var tokenFilterFactory: TokenStream => TokenStream = _
if(augment) {
  tokenFilterFactory = new AugmentingStemmingTokenFilter(_, markStems, bitPos, stemmerFactory())
}
else {
  tokenFilterFactory = new ReplacingStemmingTokenFilter(_, markStems, bitPos, stemmerFactory())
}
```

That is, I'd like the former code to act like the latter. Is this already the case?

I realize I can just try it out with some printlns, but maybe someone can throw light on any limitations on bytecode optimizations that affect this scenario?

Comment: "I realize I can just try it out " exactly!

Comment: Thanks for the motivation :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
def condition(): Boolean = {
  println("conditional evaluated")
  true
}
private val intModifier: Int => Int =
  if(condition()) {
    _ + 1
  } else {
    _ - 1
  }

intModifier(1)
intModifier(2)
```

output:

```
condition: condition[]() => Boolean



conditional evaluated
intModifier: Int => Int = <function1>


res0: Int = 2
res1: Int = 3
```

so the `val` version works as expected, i.e. the bytecode is already optimized.